# Flutter AWS S3 - Bucket policy issue. File uploads successfully then giving access deneid

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, flutter, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

This is related to policy of aws s3 bucket. I am able to upload images on bucket but when I open URL it does not show and showing access deneid. I have to make it public manually so it will show.

I have follow all steps as below
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtilitySample

Even naitve android is same. So it must be issue with bucket policy. Can anyone help me for this?

Flutter plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/amazon_s3_cognito

Comment: What is your bucket policy?

Comment: It is showing blank.

Comment: if you want bucket to be public need to add [specific](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html) policy to it.

Comment: can you double-check you unauth role has the right permissions?

Comment: got solution? same issue getting.